# A one-word synonym for "someone who wears his heart on his sleeve"?

Tags: single-word-requests, idioms, adjectives

While there's an antonym "composed" which is an antonym, I couldn't find a short synonym to describe someone who wears his heart on his sleeve. Can you think of one?

Comment: I don't think "composed" is an antonym of that. Such a person is emotionally candid, not erratic.

Comment: Authentic? Vulnerable? An open book? Transparent? Drama Queen?

Answer (score 1):

Such a person (and their behaviour) is **unrestrained**.

From [Collins Cobuild Advanced English Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/unrestrained):

> *unrestrained* adj
>
> If you describe someone's behaviour as unrestrained, you mean that it
>   is extreme or intense, for example because they are expressing their
>   feelings strongly or loudly.

Via [WFMT`S Audio Library, via Chicago Tribune.com](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1ASRM_enGB617GB618&ei=cxt1XpDfK9qChbIP7JKPmAo&q=+Drury+obviously+enjoys+his+job+%22He+is+unrestrained+in+his%22&oq=+Drury+obviously+enjoys+his+job+%22He+is+unrestrained+in+his%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...21588.23613..24294...1.0..0.69.180.3......0....2j1..gws-wiz.nwGvemdCPTo&ved=0ahUKEwjQ5InR5qnoAhVaQUEAHWzJA6MQ4dUDCAs&uact=5):

> 'Drury obviously enjoys his job ... and he is unrestrained in his
>   enthusiasm.'

And from [France 24](https://www.france24.com/en/20200301-igor-matovic-the-untamed-leader-of-slovakia-s-opposition):

> Speaking to AFP on condition of anonymity, a former associate called Matovic "a phenomenon". "He is an extremely proficient communicator.
>   He is unrestrained and sincere – sometimes too sincere," they said.

'*Abandoned*' and '**uninhibited**' are other possibilities.

> *uninhibited* adj
>
> 1 Expressing one's feelings or thoughts unselfconsciously and without
>   restraint.
>
> ‘a lively and uninhibited girl’

[[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/uninhibited)]

'Abandoned' may convey too much wildness, impropriety.

Answer (score 0):

How about "overly sensitive" or "touchy"?

If you are looking for a more neutral rather than negative connotation, "open" or "transparent" might work.

Comment: I'm not sure it means that [at all](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/origin-of-wear-heart-on-sleeve). On the contrary such a person may be emotionally stable.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but I think both of them have a somewhat negative meaning, don't they? Which the sleeve idiom doesn't

Comment: Someone who has their heart on their sleeve has their emotions on display to everyone. They're often incapable of hiding their emotions. If they're happy, you know it. If they're sad, you know it.

Answer (score 0):

Someone who expresses their emotions freely and openly is generally said to be *emotional.*